# Jedis - Missing HostPort class for simple program

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm viewing [RedisLab first course for Java developer](https://university.redislabs.com/courses/course-v1:redislabs+RU102J+2019_05/courseware/e705a681da864319a38947db2d14f3fb/4acbac1f346b499e8c2e438f170d4771/),

In Hello World program they are using `HostPort` which isn't found in [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/find/master):

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(HostPort.getRedisHost(), HostPort.getRedisPort());
```

What is `HostPort` class and why I can't find it?

There's [HostAndPort](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/HostAndPort.java), but it doesn't have those methods or similar getPort static methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code you have a constructor to input these values

```
 public HostAndPort(String host, int port)
```

for the example, I guess you can use localhost and port 6379 that is the common port for redis

in the code example of redislabs you have the class:

```
package com.redislabs.university.RU102J;

public class HostPort {

final private static String defaultHost = "localhost";

final private static Integer defaultPort = 6379;

static {
}

public static String getRedisHost() {
    return defaultHost;
}

public static Integer getRedisPort() {
    return defaultPort;
}
}
```

make sure you downloaded the code source

Comment: But the code use `HostPort` and not `HostAndPort` (and with static methods)

Comment: I edited my answer, look at the class package to find it